# Unable to load Image ImageMagick for PHP on Azure

Tags: php, azure, imagemagick

So, I have started to explore Azure, and trying to setup a PHP, MySQL on my Free Azure tier.
I have a WebApp setup on Azure, and `phpinfo()` is coming up nicely.
I am getting trouble setting up ImageMagick though.

I am on on the default PHP 5.4.42
I downloaded the extension dlls for ImageMagick from https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows

Specifically, i got the http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.1.2/php_imagick-3.1.2-5.4-nts-vc9-x86.zip file, which is nts version for PHP 5.4

Next, i followed the steps at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/

I created a folder under my wwwroot folder called 'bin'. So now mu site path looks like `/site/wwwroot/bin`.
In this bin folder, i copied the `php_imagick.dll` file AND the other 8 `Core_RL*.*` files.

Next, In my Azure app settings, i added `PHP_EXTENSIONS` key, with value `bin\php_imagick.dll`

I then restarted my web app, but i am only getting the below error in my azure logs:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0

As alternatives, now I have changed my PHP version to 5.6(latest on Azure), and have put the corresponding version of imagick files from pecl site. This did not fix anything.

I have also tried the ini method, by creating ext and ini folders under the site folder, and creating the corresponding 'PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR' setting, but on restart of app, nothing shows up in the phpinfo(). Very sad :(

Please suggest what can I attempt to fix this issue.

Comment: maybe you can try the other method using `ini` file

Comment: @Ansel, thanks for your response. I had tried the `ini` method already earlier, but just tried it again, but it didn't help :( I have updated the original post to indicate this now.

Comment: How many Instances your App is running on

Comment: @ZeeMoussa, sorry i am quite new to Azure so might not know exactly what you are asking for. I am on the free app and free DB tier, so it would be the lowest offering they have. Does this help? Else you may guide me what I need to check to give you the info you need.

Comment: @ZeeMoussa, its one instance. Just found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all the versions of Imagemagick are compatible. 
Here  is a repo https://github.com/snobu/php-imagick-webapps that has the right resources referenced.

Download these resources (NTS Versions)

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.3.0rc2/php_imagick-3.3.0rc2-5.6-nts-vc11-x86.zip
http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.2-8-Q16-x86-dll.exe

Follow the steps in this Article, It just works http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/12/01/php-imagemagick-on-azure-web-apps.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I had seen this article in my search earlier, but it looks to "invasive" and I went past it. So now post your comment, I tried it out and it actually helped install the extension! Thanks. For others benefit, I tweaked the steps a bit to play perhaps a bit better with Azure default PHP. I copied the files as mentioned in the article, but from the xdt file i omitted the fastCgi section. I also did noto copy any php56.ini file. Post, this the default ini setup method worked and brought it up on Phpinfo(). I am now getting a font path error, but that would be another effort.

Comment: I have now shared my steps at http://techblog.saurabhkumar.com/2015/12/setting-up-imagemagick-for-php-on-azure.html. Looks too much work due to number of steps involved,, but I will try to simplify the steps in coming days.

Comment: I hope that the integration improves in future, this is basically the IIS running a PHP website, and hence one needs to go for right kind of NTS dll's